# C++ Reading playlist without specific delimiter for albums

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm creating a C++ program to simulate a Jukebox and all is well so far. However I am supposed to read albums from a file and I'm having trouble coming up with a way to separate albums when reading from the file given the format I have to use for the playlist file.

The given format for the playlist file is as follows:

```
Album
Number of songs
Song title|Artist|Duration in sec
```

And a sample of the actual playlist file:

```
Abbey Road
17
Come Together|The Beatles|260
Something|The Beatles|183
Maxwell's Silver Hammer|The Beatles|207
Oh! Darling|The Beatles|206
Octopus's Garden|The Beatles|171
I Want You (She's So Heavy)|The Beatles|467
Here Comes the Sun|The Beatles|185
Because|The Beatles|165
You Never Give Me Your Money|The Beatles|242
Sun King|The Beatles|146
Mean Mr. Mustard|The Beatles|66
Polythene Pam|The Beatles|72
She Came in Through the Bathroom Window|The Beatles|117
Golden Slumbers|The Beatles|91
Carry That Weight|The Beatles|96
The End|The Beatles|139
Her Majesty|The Beatles|23
Rubber Soul
14
Drive My Car|The Beatles|150
Norwegian Wood|The Beatles|125
You Won't See Me|The Beatles|202
Nowhere Man|The Beatles|164
Think For Yourself|The Beatles|138
The Word|The Beatles|161
Michelle|The Beatles|160
What Goes On|The Beatles|170
Girl|The Beatles|153
I'm Looking Through You|The Beatles|147
In My Life|The Beatles|148
Wait|The Beatles|136
If I Needed Someone|The Beatles|143
Run For Your Life|The Beatles|138
```

I have a Class named Song with relevant parts below:

```
class Song
{
    private:
        std::string title;
        std::string artist;
        Time duration;
        ...
};
```

And a class named Album with relevant parts below:

```
class Album
{
    private:
        std::string album_title;
        int numsongs;
        std::vector<Song> songvec;
        ...
};
```

Overloaded >> operator for Song:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Song &song)
{
    Time t;
    string str;

    getline(is, str, DELIM);
    song.setTitle(str);

    getline(is, str, DELIM);
    song.setArtist(str);

    is >> t;
    song.setDuration(t);

    return is;
}
```

Overloaded >> operator for Album:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Album &album)
{
    Song s;
    string str;

    getline(is, str);
    album.setAlbum(str);

    getline(is, str);
    int num_songs = 0;
    stringstream numstream(str);
    numstream >> num_songs;
    album.setNumSongs(num_songs);

    while(is >> s)
        album.addSong(s);

    return is;
}
```

Overloaded >> operator for Time:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Time &t)
{
    int duration;
    is >> duration;

    t.setHour((duration / 3600) % 60);
    t.setMinute((duration / 60) % 60);
    t.setSecond(duration % 60);

    return is;
}
```

The openFromFile function:

```
void Jukebox::openFromFile()
{
    fstream inFile(INFILE, ios::in);
    Album a;

    if(!albvec.empty())
        albvec.clear();

    while(inFile >> a)
        albvec.push_back(a);

    inFile.close();
}
```

The problem is that I end up with the first Album title and the first number of songs in an album in the correct data members, but all the rest of the data in the songvec. I sort of know what is wrong but I'm having trouble coming up with a method to tell the instream when a new album begins. The problem should be somewhere around these lines in the >> operator for Album.

```
while(is >> s)
    album.addSong(s);
```

This is university "homework" and as such I am not allowed to change formats for the playlist file. Thanks in advance for any hints and pointers in the right direction.

Comment: You should remove the `numsongs` member of `Album` and use `songvec.size()` instead. Using a separate member might cause a source of problems, when you forget to update the one or the other.

Comment: Yeah, I did use both in my prototype code. Not entirely sure why I added that numsongs member really.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the number of songs in an album to read them :

```
for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < num_songs; ++i)
{
  is >> s;
  album.addSong(s);
}
```

Because in your code, you will read the name of the next album in the while loop.

Comment: Yes but of course! I do read the number of songs before I read the actual songs. Bad brain day today.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw my code was wrong. Correction done.